# erlang cowboy websocket- number of open sockets

Tags: websocket, erlang, cowboy

I have written an Erlang chat backend, using the cowboy module.

I'm trying to figure out how can i log the number of open web sockets connections, that are currently connected.

I have been looking for an answer to this question for a while, and i couldn't find one.

Do you have any idea how it could be done?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 4):

Do count your websocket into `websocket_init` or `websocket_handle`
I write down the information of the public in websocket `ets` table

Add information websocket about:

```
websocket_handle({text, Msg}, Req, State) ->
            ets:insert(systbl_websockets, {self(), get_current, other_info}),
            {reply, [{text, <<"ok">>}], Req, State, hibernate};
    end;
```

Remove information websocket about:

```
websocket_terminate(_Reason, _Req, _State) ->
    lager:debug("Close connection"),
    ets:delete(systbl_websockets, self()),
    {ok, _Req, _State, shutdown}.
```

Comment: i have implemented a counter, iterating over all the processes, with initial call of {cowboy_protocol,init,4}

this seems to work just fine

Comment: @user1668328 That (process iteration) sounds technically a bit dodgy to me. At the very least it could break easily due to changes to cowboy. I have to say I prefer the solution posted by the answerer.